# How to design a shelving unit out of McMaster Carr Struts?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structures, statics, beam

I apologize for the complete beginner question.

I'm an Undergraduate Research Assistant trying to design a shelving 8'tall  by 10' Long, 4' wide shelving unit to support about 200 lbs. I'm designing this to go over 4' 8' table, so the folks in the lab can reach up and grab any of our optical equipment easily.

My question, is how to get started? I've had luck finding components on McMaster-Carr for Struts(https://www.mcmaster.com/#struts/=1b21hmv) and braces, but I'm completely new to building things in general, and I'm trying to avoid any stupid mistakes.

Can anyone point me to any resources or tips to get started? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is an example of the thing I'm trying to build

[image]

Comment: Have you seen other shelves anywhere - take a good look at them - think about how they will be loaded - tipping hazard, load capacity, objects at height etc.

Comment: The example seems to be constructed out of [Unistrut](http://www.unistrut.us/) components (also available from McMaster). A video showing how to build a shelf system using unistrut is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-8RJcGWA5o).

Comment: @BobT  Thank you so much.  That video looks fantastic, I'll take a look!